# Reshape aggregated rows to new columns, categorical data

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to use R to aggregate rows to columns. Here is a sample of my dataset.

```
age sex hash                                emotion     color
22  1   b17f9762462b37e7510f0e6d2534530d    Lonely      #006666
22  1   b17f9762462b37e7510f0e6d2534530d    Energetic   #66CC00
22  1   b17f9762462b37e7510f0e6d2534530d    Calm        #FFFFFF
22  1   b17f9762462b37e7510f0e6d2534530d    Angry       #FF0000
24  1   7bb50ca97a9b517239b39440a966d2f6    Calm        #006666
24  1   7bb50ca97a9b517239b39440a966d2f6    Excited     #0033cc
24  1   7bb50ca97a9b517239b39440a966d2f6    Empty/void  #999999
24  1   7bb50ca97a9b517239b39440a966d2f6    No emotion  #FF6600
26  1   209f1ba8ef86e855deccc0aae120825c    Comfortable #330066
21  1   b9e9309c0b1255a7efb2edf9ba66ae46    Energetic   #330099
21  1   b9e9309c0b1255a7efb2edf9ba66ae46    Happy       #330066
26  1   209f1ba8ef86e855deccc0aae120825c    No emotion  #FFCC00
26  1   209f1ba8ef86e855deccc0aae120825c    Calm        #006666
21  1   61debd3dea6d1aacce5c9fc7daec4fe5    Empty/void  #FFFFFF
21  1   b9e9309c0b1255a7efb2edf9ba66ae46    Calm        #006666
26  1   209f1ba8ef86e855deccc0aae120825c    No emotion  #339900
21  1   61debd3dea6d1aacce5c9fc7daec4fe5    Loved       #FF6600
26  1   209f1ba8ef86e855deccc0aae120825c    No emotion  #66CC00
```

What I want to do is get this:

```
age sex hash            #000000 #FF0000 ... #FFFFFF
22  1   8798tkojstwz9ei sad     happy   ... loved
...
```

One response is defined by the hash, associated data is age and sex.

I want to have each response as 1 instead of several columns. Each color should have it's own column and the associated emotion as value of that column.

The whole dataset has 13 colors, 20+ emotions and 1000+ responses. The dataset looks exactly as the sample and is stored in a mySQL database.

I have tried with reshape, but it doesn't play well with categorical data or I did not use the appropriate functions. Any ideas? It can include some mySQL preparation if needed. Java was here very slow and since I have 12k+ rows R sounds like the right thing for this.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that `aggregate` is an appropriate title (or tag) for this question. Can you consider re-titling the question to something that more precisely describes where your problem lies?

Comment: sure, what do you suggest?

Comment: Not sure! It all depends on where you got stuck, since that is where others might also get stuck if attempting similar tasks. More accurate titles and tags will increase the chances of those users finding the answers they're looking for. Welcome to SO, by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, `reshape()` is indeed the function you're looking for. Assuming your dataset is called `mydf`, try this:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar = c("hash", "age", "sex"), 
        timevar = "color")
#    age sex                             hash emotion.#006666 emotion.#66CC00
# 1   22   1 b17f9762462b37e7510f0e6d2534530d          Lonely       Energetic
# 5   24   1 7bb50ca97a9b517239b39440a966d2f6            Calm            <NA>
# 9   26   1 209f1ba8ef86e855deccc0aae120825c            Calm      No emotion
# 10  21   1 b9e9309c0b1255a7efb2edf9ba66ae46            Calm            <NA>
# 14  21   1 61debd3dea6d1aacce5c9fc7daec4fe5            <NA>            <NA>
# emotion.#FFFFFF emotion.#FF0000 emotion.#0033cc emotion.#999999 emotion.#FF6600
# 1             Calm           Angry            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
# 5             <NA>            <NA>         Excited      Empty/void      No emotion
# 9             <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
# 10            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
# 14      Empty/void            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>           Loved
# emotion.#330066 emotion.#330099 emotion.#FFCC00 emotion.#339900
# 1             <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
# 5             <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
# 9      Comfortable            <NA>      No emotion      No emotion
# 10           Happy       Energetic            <NA>            <NA>
# 14            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
```

You can rename the columns later if you need to.

Comment: next time I will beat you with a reshape solution :)

Comment: @agstudy, are you talking base R, or "reshape2" ;) -- Anyway, I think it's always good to have a couple of answers to show the OP what options are available.

Answer (score 2):

using `reshape2`

```
dcast(dat,...~color,value.var='emotion')
  age sex                             hash #0033cc #006666     #330066   #330099   #339900   #66CC00 #999999 #FF0000   #FF6600
1  21   1 61debd3dea6d1aacce5c9fc7daec4fe5    <NA>    <NA>        <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     Loved
2  21   1 b9e9309c0b1255a7efb2edf9ba66ae46    <NA>    Calm       Happy Energetic      <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
3  22   1 b17f9762462b37e7510f0e6d2534530d    <NA>  Lonely        <NA>      <NA>      <NA> Energetic    <NA>   Angry      <NA>
4  24   1 7bb50ca97a9b517239b39440a966d2f6 Excited    Calm        <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>   Empty    <NA> Noemotion
5  26   1 209f1ba8ef86e855deccc0aae120825c    <NA>    Calm Comfortable      <NA> Noemotion Noemotion    <NA>    <NA>      <NA>
    #FFCC00 #FFFFFF
1      <NA>   Empty
2      <NA>    <NA>
3      <NA>    Calm
4      <NA>    <NA>
5 Noemotion    <NA>
```

Comment: when I use your function I get the following warning: "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length". The result is a table with 1 and 0 for values instead of the categorical emotion values.

Comment: @frinx The output shows that it works for me. Which version of reshape2 are u using? it depends also how I read your data. can you dput(head(dat)) to test ?

Comment: i just downloaded and installed reshape2 so it should be the latest. dput(head(dat)) outputs: structure(list(age = c(22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L), sex = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sessionid = structure(c(679L, 679L, 679L, 
679L, 679L, 679L), .Label = c([list of hashes])), class = "factor"), emotion = structure(c(16L, 10L, 4L, 19L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c([list of emotions]), class = "factor"), color = structure(c(3L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 12L), .Label = c([list of colors]), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", "sex", "hash", "emotion", "color"), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")